# How to inspect CloudShell persistent disk in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

I'm reading:

> Cloud Shell provisions 5 GB of free persistent disk storage mounted as your `$HOME` directory on the virtual machine instance. This storage is on a per-user basis and is available across projects. Unlike the instance itself, this storage does not time out on inactivity. All files you store in your home directory, including installed software, scripts and user configuration files like `.bashrc` and `.vimrc`, persist between sessions. Your `$HOME` directory is private to you and can't be accessed by other users.

However I am not able to find this persistent disk in the GUI and inspect the size and contents of it. Where does it reside in the GCP console? Can I inspect and change the specs of it. e.g. specify SSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The per-user storage is managed by Google and you cannot access it directly - only when attached to the Cloud Shell container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Any link to support this? As well, does it mean as a user I will be always provided this only disk whatsoever?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov - I am not aware of a document stating that - I just know the internals. I wrote an extensive Cloud Shell interface in Go that I released on GitHub that will show you some secrets. I am not sure what you are asking in your second sentence. The provisioned storage is per Google account user. You get one instance (5 GB) of this storage. The storage is attached to a Google managed virtual machine. Your environment is a Docker container running on that virtual machine with the storage mounted at your $HOME directory. The storage is private to your identity.